# Why badges are not removed after voting score changes?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I ask a question for which I receive 10 upvotes. I get *Nice Question* badge because of that.

Suppose an hour later, 4 people downvote my question: my badge will still be there and will never be removed. Is this a bug? Or is there an other explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [SE Meta website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178013/302595):

> With the exception of tag badges, you keep whatever badge you earned -
>   even if you no longer meet the criteria.
>
> ---
>
> There are some rare cases, where a badge will be manually removed when
>   there is fraud involved. But those are rare scenarios, and are only
>   done in extreme circumstances.

Comment: You always have the right answer, Mysterious Smart Man :). Thank you very much.